# Check my registration date

Tags: support, registration

How can I check my Stack Overflow registration date?

Taking a look at my profile, I can only see how many months I've been on the site.

Comment: Related: [How to know “exact date of account creation” on StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63336/how-to-know-exact-date-of-account-creation-on-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A lot of date/time related fields on this site have tool-tips, which you can see by hovering your mouse over the text.

So in your profile, if you hover over the "11 months" you see:

> [image]

Most other "event" related items do this as well. If you see a newer post it might say "answered X [seconds/minutes/hours] ago", or similar. Hovering over the words will show the precise date and time.

Comment: Just as an aside, I have seen many other websites adopt this trend.  More often than not whenever a website replaces a date with some shorthand estimate, hovering over it produces the full DateTime stamp information.  Try this on Facebook messages, gchat messages, Twitter, etc.

Comment: Twitch was using it but it seems they returned to normal date. This short version with hover title is honestly terrible. When you try to find something through giant list of '1 month ago' and have to hover over every date to actually see the day, you will understand :)