# How to see time of recent posts

Tags: support, timestamps

I recently came across three answers that were posted around the same time (all of them read *23 hours ago* right now) for [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106282/is-there-a-way-i-can-print-multiple-lines-using-one-print/) that was asked on *Feb 14 at 1:26*.

They are almost the same answer with very minor differences. In fact, (the more recent) two probably should be comments to the oldest one. But I can't see which one was posted first. I can see the precise time of the older answers: *answered Feb 14 at 1:30*, etc. How do we see the exact time of recent posts?

Comment: Precise UTC timestamps are available as tooltips on hovering.

Comment: @Oleg: But not on mobile, for which the timeline view would be a good alternative. See my answer below.

Comment: What is the canonical for the hovering? [A lead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53627/improve-the-accuracy-of-time-strings/53628#53628) from 2010.

Comment: @Peter: Maybe this one? [Display minutes in the "answered X hours ago" item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30108/display-minutes-in-the-answered-x-hours-ago-item).. Here's an earlier one: [Add year to time date stamps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/add-year-to-time-date-stamps).. And even earlier: [Add year to question and answer dates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/add-year-to-question-and-answer-dates)

Comment: @Peter: The earliest post regarding on-hover timestamps I could find on MSO: [Check my registration date](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269377/check-my-registration-date/269379#269379)

Comment: Related: [Make the precision of display ages and dates/times consistent, regardless of their age](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369774/284827)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the exact time of *any* post by hovering over the time, whether it is currently being displayed with relative time or not.

In this example, hovering over "23 hours ago" will reveal the exact UTC timestamp which was "2022-06-11 03:55:02Z"

[image: Usercard with post time display of "23 hours ago" reveals timestamp "2022-06-11 03:55:02Z"]

Again this works even if it is not showing a relative time. Hovering over "Feb 14 at 1:30" will reveal "2022-02-14 01:30:20Z":

[image: Usercard with post time display of "Feb 14 at 1:30" with tooltip "2022-02-14 01:30:20Z"]

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative is to go to the [timeline view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/513150) *of the question* and select "toggle format" in the header of the left-most column:

[image]

This makes it easier to see the exact timestamps of all the answers in one place.

This is also a good alternative since hovering to see timestamps is not possible on *mobile*.

Although, if you just want to see who posted *first*, the events in the timeline view are sorted from newest to oldest, so you can easily see who posted their answer first without looking at the exact timestamps.

Comment: Too bad that figuring out how to get the exact timestamps in the timeline requires either being psychic or having Meta knowledge (and even then, I definitely forgot). Also, tooltips don't work on screen readers either (as far as I can figure out).